# Does the manga continue the story from the anime?

Tags: full-moon-wo-sagashite

I just finished watching *Full Moon wo Sagashite*. I wished it got 2nd season, but that's not going to happen. So, I decided to read the manga.

However, does the manga continue the story from the anime's ending? If yes, from which chapter?

Comment: Before you read, please note that [there are some differences between the manga and anime version](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/228/whats-the-difference-between-the-full-moon-wo-sagashite-manga-and-anime?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, and the anime does in fact end (so why would there be a second season?).

The manga and anime are similar, but they diverge and quite significantly at some point so that you might consider them alternate tellings of the same story.

As Aki pointed out, there are a number of [differences between the manga and the anime version](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/228/whats-the-difference-between-the-full-moon-wo-sagashite-manga-and-anime).

It's been a while since I've seen and read them, but I believe the overall story is more or less the same except for the ending.